# iPhone rotation applied to a 3d object

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, core-motion

The quaternion you get from CMAttitude seems flawed. In Unity I can get the iPhone's rotation, apply it to a 3d object, and the object will rotate as you rotate the iPhone. In Xcode it seems to be different.

To set up a quick test project, follow these steps:

1. In Xcode, create a new project from the **iOS > Game template** (this gives us a 3d object to test on).
2. In `GameViewController.h` add `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>` and `@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;`
3. In `GameViewController.m` remove the animation at line:46 `[ship runAction: etc..` and don't allow camera control at line:55 (not necessary)
4. In `GameViewController.m` add to bottom of ViewDidLoad

   ```
   self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
   self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = .1;

   [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
        withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

            CMQuaternion q = motion.attitude.quaternion;
            ship.rotation = SCNVector4Make(q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w);

            if(error){ NSLog(@"%@", error); }
   } ];
   ```
5. To avoid annoyances, in Project > Targets > *Project Name* > Deployment Info > Device Orientation, allow only Portrait (or just lock your iPhone's rotation)

When I build this to my iPhone the 3d object (an airplane) doesn't follow the rotation of the phone. Pitching kind of works.

Is this intended? How am I using this wrong?

Comment: Using `ship.orientation` instead of `ship.rotation` solves the issue. Thanks @orangenkopf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3D space there are different representations of rotations.
You are using the `rotation` property of `SCNNode`:

> The four-component rotation vector specifies the direction 
>   of the rotation axis in the first three components and the 
>   angle of rotation (in radians) in the fourth.

But you are assigning the device rotation as [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Either assign the quaternion to the [`orientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408048-orientation) property of `SCNNode` or use the yaw, pitch and roll angles of [`CMAttitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitude) and assign these to the [`eulerAngles`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles) property of `SCNNode`:

> The node’s orientation, expressed as pitch, yaw, and roll angles, 
>   each in radians.